# Using Hoeffding's Inequality, how can I get smaller errors as I increase the number samples, N?

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, self-learning, mathematical-modeling

The following is Hoeffding’s Inequality:

$P(|\nu - \mu| > \epsilon) \leq 2e^{-2\epsilon^2N}$

How can I use the above inequality to actually see how the upper bound changes as I change the sample size $N$ and tolerance $\epsilon$? $\mu$ is the population parameter and $\nu$ is the sample parameter which helps infer $\mu$ in the population.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed $\epsilon > 0$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Notice that:
\begin{align*}2e^{-2\epsilon^2 N} \leq \alpha
&\iff e^{-2\epsilon^2N} \leq \frac\alpha2\\
&\iff e^{2\epsilon^2N} \geq \frac2\alpha \\
&\iff 2\epsilon^2N\geq \log(\frac2\alpha) \\
&\iff N \geq \frac{\log(\frac2\alpha)}{2\epsilon^2}.
\end{align*}
Therefore, Hoeffding's inequality shows that the event $|\nu - \mu| \leq \epsilon$ will happen with probability greater than $1-\alpha$ if you choose $N \geq \dfrac{\log(\frac2\alpha)}{2\epsilon^2}$.

Comment: I understand the first line and I am lost.

Comment: @user122358: is it better now?